# React-leaflet map CSS loading error with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-leaflet

I am trying to get to work `react-leaflet` library with Next.js. When importing the following:

```js
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css'
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";
```

I am getting the following error:

> ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
> ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)`.

I was supposed to add loader in my webpack, but because I have `next.config.js` I thought I can do it there.

My `next.config.js` file's content is:

```
// Вырубаем css-modules для css файлов
    const cssRule = config.module.rules.find(item => item.test && item.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/');
    if (cssRule) {
        const cssLoader = cssRule.use.find(item => item.loader && item.loader.startsWith('css-loader'));
        if (cssLoader) {
            cssLoader.options.modules = false;
        }
    }
```

and

```
config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|png|gif|svg|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name]-[hash:8].[ext]',
              publicPath: (url) => {
                return `/_next/static/css/${url}`;
              },
              outputPath: `${isServer ? '../' : ''}static/css/`,
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      });
```

Code was written initially by someone else. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't require any webpack configuration to load CSS files, [Next.js has built-in support for it](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules).